# Python: Append from one dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 10 000 rows.
I need to extract the rows into a new dataframe according to a condition (where name is in name_list)

What is the easiest way to do this

Comment: I used newdf = df.loc[df['Name'].isin(namelist)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your dataframe structure and name:
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(record, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage']

Accordingly, the new dataframe can be created as :

rslt_df = dataframe[dataframe['Name'].isin(name_list)]

alternatively, you can use :

rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Name'].isin(name_list)]

Answer (score 0):

U can use for loop to iterate through each rows in the df

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)//row is an array which contain your each column data'[name, age,....]
```

so you can use your condition in this for loop and filter the rows

or you can use UDF finction to do this by calling df.apply(UDF())